# Grouping Case In highCharts

Tags: highcharts

In my angularJS app I have data that looks like this:
For each month of the year I have this:

```
JAN:
      2023  2024
Asset 1 5   6
Asset 2 4   7
Asset 3 5   6

FEB:
      2023  2024
Asset 1 3   1
Asset 2 6   2
Asset 3 7   5
```

....

(I can of course change the structure if needed)

Now, I want to create a graph that will help my users to  `debug`  their values so, I want to show then for each month, 2 bars, one for last year and one for current year. each bar is the stack of many assets.

So X axis should be the Month and for each Month should be 2 years.
And in the labels should appear each asset only once. (don't create 2 copies of the same asset one for this year and one for the other, since the user might want to isolate one asset only).

I've tried to use the Group by option but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Again. I was probably not clear enough before in the comments of the great answer of magdalena that got me really close.

I wanted this behavior:

1. If a series is clicked and it's already visible, and there's only one visible series, it will show all series.
2. If a series is clicked and it's not visible, it will toggle the visibility of that series.
3. If a series is clicked while other series are visible, it will hide all other series and show only the clicked series.

Therefore, I used this legendItemClick function:

```js
let monthlyData = {
  'JAN': {
    '2023': {
      'Asset 1': 5,
      'Asset 2': 4,
      'Asset 3': 5,
    },
    '2024': {
      'Asset 1': 6,
      'Asset 2': 7,
      'Asset 3': 6,
    }
  },
  'FEB': {
    '2023': {
      'Asset 1': 3,
      'Asset 2': 6,
      'Asset 3': 7,
    },
    '2024': {
      'Asset 2': 1,
      'Asset 3': 2,
      'Asset 4': 5,
    }
  },
};

// Categories
const categories = Object.keys(monthlyData).map(month => {
  return {
    name: month,
    categories: Object.keys(monthlyData[month])
  };
});

// Assets
let assets = new Set();
Object.values(monthlyData).forEach(month => {
  Object.values(month).forEach(year => {
    Object.keys(year).forEach(asset => {
      assets.add(asset);
    });
  });
});
assets = [...assets];

// Series
const series = assets.map(asset => {
  const data = [];

  categories.forEach(category => {
    category.categories.forEach(subcategory => {
      const monthData = monthlyData[category.name][subcategory] || {};
      const value = monthData[asset] || 0;
      data.push(value);
    });
  });

  const seriesObject = {
    name: asset,
    data
  };
  return seriesObject;
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },

  plotOptions: {
     column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    series: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function() {
    const series = this.chart.series;
    const allVisible = series.every(s => s.visible);

    // If the clicked series is already visible, and there's only one visible series, show all series
    if (this.visible && series.filter(s => s.visible).length === 1) {
        series.forEach(s => s.show());
    } else {
        series.forEach(s => {
            // Show/hide series based on whether all series are visible or not
            if (allVisible || !this.visible) {
                s === this ? s.show() : s.hide();
            } else {
                // Show the clicked series and hide others
                s === this ? s.show() : s.hide();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
      }
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: categories,
    crosshair: true,
    tickWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      groupedOptions: [{
        style: {
          visibility: 'visible',
          fontSize: '12px',
        },
      }],
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Value'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
  },

  series: series
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/grouped-categories.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will require some customization.

First of all, I would recommend using the grouped-categories plugin.

```
<script src="https://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/grouped-categories.js"></script>
```

Also, custom parsing will be necessary. I have prepared an example you can base on:

```
let monthlyData = {
  'JAN': {
    '2023': {
      'Asset 1': 5,
      'Asset 4': 4,
      'Asset 5': 5,
    },
    '2024': {
      'Asset 2': 6,
      'Asset 3': 7,
      'Asset 7': 6,
    }
  },
  'FEB': {
    '2023': {
      'Asset 6': 3,
      'Asset 2': 6,
      'Asset 3': 7,
    },
    '2024': {
      'Asset 2': 1,
      'Asset 3': 2,
      'Asset 4': 5,
    }
  },
};

// Categories
const categories = Object.keys(monthlyData).map(month => {
  return {
    name: month,
    categories: Object.keys(monthlyData[month])
  };
});

// Assets
let assets = new Set();
Object.values(monthlyData).forEach(month => {
  Object.values(month).forEach(year => {
    Object.keys(year).forEach(asset => {
      assets.add(asset);
    });
  });
});
assets = [...assets];

// Series
const series = assets.map(asset => {
  const data = [];

  categories.forEach(category => {
    category.categories.forEach(subcategory => {
      const monthData = monthlyData[category.name][subcategory] || {};
      const value = monthData[asset] || 0;
      data.push(value);
    });
  });

  const seriesObject = {
    name: asset,
    data
  };
  return seriesObject;
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: categories,
    crosshair: true,
    tickWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      groupedOptions: [{
        style: {
          visibility: 'visible',
          fontSize: '12px',
        },
      }],
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Value'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  series: series
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z1d9s7o3/

**API References:**
https://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/

---

### EDIT:

Enhanced legend interactivity based on the comment (when clicking on an series in the legend, it shows only that item and hides the rest):

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function() {
          const series = this.chart.series,
            allVisible = series.every(s => s.visible);
          series.forEach(s => {
            if (allVisible || !this.visible) {
              s === this ? s.show() : s.hide();
            } else {
              s.show();
            }
          });
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/um35o8dv/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick

Comment: amazing, thanks! 

now I have a follow-up question. 
The current behavior in the graph is when I press on one of the assets, it just disappears from the graph. but actually, what I want to happen is when I press on one asset, it makes all the other disappear and only leaving this one. (so it will be easy to compare), and when I press back on it, everything appears again. if I Press on another one, it will again the only one appearing.

Can I do that? 

thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer with the solution for the legend interactivity ;)

Comment: Thanks again. 
I was probably not clear enough before, I wanted this behavior: 
1. If a series is clicked and it's already visible, and there's only one visible series, it will show all series.
2. If a series is clicked and it's not visible, it will toggle the visibility of that series.
3. If a series is clicked while other series are visible, it will hide all other series and show only the clicked series.


Therefore I believe this function is better: